# Lexicographically smallest palindrome in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, palindrome, lowercase, lexicographic

I found this question to be interesting and I would like to share this here and find reasonably good codes, specific to py :

Given a **string S** having characters from English alphabets **['a' - 'z']** and **'.' as the special character (without quotes).** 
Write a program to construct the **lexicographically smallest palindrome** by **filling each of the faded character ('.') with a lower case alphabet.**

**Definition:**

The smallest lexicographical order is an order relation where string s is smaller than t, given the first character of s (s1 ) is smaller than the first character of t (t1 ), or in case they
are equivalent, the second character, etc.

*For example :* "aaabbb" is smaller than "aaac" because although the first three characters
are equal, the fourth character b is smaller than the fourth character c.

**Input Format:**

String S

**Output Format:**

Print lexicographically smallest palindrome after filling each **'.' character**, if it
possible to construct one. **Print -1 otherwise.**

*Example-1*

Input:
a.ba

Output:
abba

*Example-2:*

Input:
a.b

Output:
-1

**Explanation:**

In *example 1*, you can create a palindrome by filling the '.' character by 'b'.

In *example 2*, it is not possible to make the string s a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy paste questions from NPTEL assignments and ask them here without even trying!
Anyways,since the "code" is your only concern,try copy pasting the lines below:

```
    word = input()
    length = len(word)
    def SmallestPalindrome(word, length):
        i = 0
        j = length - 1
        word = list(word)  #creating a list from the input word
        while (i <= j):  
              if (word[i] == word[j] == '.'): 
                  word[i] = word[j] = 'a'  
              elif word[i] != word[j]:  
                  if (word[i] == '.'):
                     word[i] = word[j]
                  elif (word[j] == '.'):
                     word[j] = word[i]
                  else:  # worst case situation when palindrome condition is not met
                     return -1
             i = i + 1  
             j = j - 1 
        return "".join(word)  # to turn the list back to a string
    print(SmallestPalindrome(word, length)) #Print the output of your function
```

Comment: I believe I said this,'I found this question to be interesting and I would like to share this here' before posting the question. Yes, It is from NPTEL, why would I deny it. FYI, I did try my own codes, but I just couldn't get the hang of it, and I tried searching on the Internet to this particular question. I thought I could get better answers from good coders around here. I just wanted to share this and get to know all the possible codes I could have tried it with. I am sorry if I have offended you.